# TypeError: Cannot read property 'authenticated' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently having this problem as I'm not sure whats the problem here. Either my brain doesn't work since I've worked on this project for more than 5 hours right now and when I tried to run this, it shows this error

```html
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'authenticated' of undefined
    at module.exports (my directory\api\policies\userInfo.js:6:21)
```

I'm not sure what part should I share here but here the main thing.

userInfo.js

```js
/*jslint node: true, unparam: true, nomen: true*/
/*global User*/
"use strict";

module.exports = function (req, res, next){
    if (req.session.authenticated && req.session.userid && req.session.userid > 0) {
        User.findOne({
            id: req.session.userid
        }, function (err, user) {
            res.locals.__user = user;
            next();
        });
    } else {
        next();
    }
};
```

authController

```js
/*jslint node: true, unparam: true*/
/*global User, LogService*/
"use strict";

module.exports = {
    login: function (req, res) {
        var username = req.param('username'),
            password = req.param('password');

        User.findOne({
            Name: username
        }, function (err, user) {
            if (err || !user) {
                LogService.login(req.ip, 'hat versucht sich als ' + username + ' anzumelden. Der Benutzername existiert nicht.');
                res.view('auth/message', {
                    active: 'login',
                    title: 'Live Your Dream - Anmelden',
                    error: 'Der angegebene Benutzername existiert nicht.',
                });
            } else {
                if (user.validPassword(password)) {
                    req.session.authenticated = true;
                    req.session.userid = user.id;
                    LogService.login(req.ip, 'hat sich erfolgreich als ' + username + ' angemeldet.');
                    //res.redirect('/login/success');
                    res.redirect('/user/' + username);
                } else {
                    LogService.login(req.ip, 'hat versucht sich als ' + username + ' anzumelden. Das passwort war falsch.');
                    req.session.loginAttempts = (req.session.loginAttempts || 0) + 1;
                    if (req.session.loginAttempts >= 3) {
                        req.session.restrictLogin = new Date().getTime() + (20 * 60 * 1000); //20 Minuten in Millisekunden
                    }
                    res.view('auth/message', {
                        active: 'login',
                        title: 'Live Your Dream - Anmelden',
                        error: 'Das angegebene Passwort ist falsch.',
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    },

    successLogin: function (req, res) {
        res.view('auth/message', {
            active: 'login',
            title: 'Live Your Dream - Anmelden',
            success: 'Du wurdest erfolgreich angemeldet.'
        });
    },

    logout: function (req, res) {
        if (req.session.authenticated) {
            req.session.authenticated = false;
            delete req.session.authenticated;
            delete req.session.userid;
            res.redirect('/logout/success');
        } else {
            res.view('auth/message', {
                active: 'login',
                title: 'Live Your Dream - Abmelden',
                error: 'Du bist nicht angemeldet.'
            });
        }
    },

    succesLogout: function (req, res) {
        res.view('auth/message', {
            active: 'login',
            title: 'Live Your Dream - Anmelden',
            success: 'Du wurdest erfolgreich abgemeldet.'
        });
    },

    view: function (req, res) {
        if (req.session.restrictLogin && req.session.restrictLogin > new Date().getTime()) {
            res.view('auth/restricted', {
                active: 'login',
                title: 'Live Your Dream - Anmelden'
            });
        } else {
            if (req.session.restrictLogin) {
                delete req.session.restrictLogin;
                delete req.session.loginAttempts;
            }
            res.view('auth/login', {
                active: 'login',
                title: 'Live Your Dream - Anmelden'
            });
        }
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You must be calling this userInfo.js with a req that has an uninitialized session. One way to solve this is to handle the case where req.session is undefined.